# Asp.net MVC Login Implementation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-membership, cloud

I'm developing a cloud application. I'm confuse about my login system implementation, which one is best for me?

1. What about Asp.net Membership class?
2. Secondly about the Form authentication and Session Implementation

Remember this application is on cloud, so please give suggestion according to scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest ASP.NET Membership Class. Its an industry standard and it eases handling of many login related features including:

1. User lockout after certain number of login attempts.
2. Security Question and answer.
3. Password encryption and hashing.
4. Session management.

Especially considering it being on the cloud, if you were supposed to lets say up the security for the site by making accounts to lock after one failed login attempt, it would be just a Web.config change.

Being a completely tested solution, ASP.NET membership provider is best approach.